# Install Windows Service with Recovery action to Restart

Tags: .net, windows-services, service

I'm installing a Windows Service using the `ServiceProcessInstaller` and `ServiceInstaller` classes.

I've used the `ServiceProcessInstaller` to set the start type, name, etc. But **how do I set the recovery action to Restart?**

I know I can do it manually after the service is installed by going to the Services management console and changing the settings on the recovery tab of the service's properties, but is there a way to do it during the install?

[image: Service Property Recovery Tab]

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You can set the recovery options using [sc](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490995.aspx).  The following will set the service to restart after a failure:

```
sc failure [servicename] reset= 0 actions= restart/60000
```

This can easily be called from C#:

```
static void SetRecoveryOptions(string serviceName)
{
    int exitCode;
    using (var process = new Process())
    {
        var startInfo = process.StartInfo;
        startInfo.FileName = "sc";
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

        // tell Windows that the service should restart if it fails
        startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("failure \"{0}\" reset= 0 actions= restart/60000", serviceName);

        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();

        exitCode = process.ExitCode;
    }

    if (exitCode != 0)
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

Comment: Note that you need to include service name in quotation marks, if it contains spaces.

Comment: If you're going to call this from the Installer[] service install handler in C# when the service installs, you can insert this call into the "Committed" event handler which will execute it just after the service appears in Service Control Manager. Don't put it in the "AfterInstall" event manager, as it this won't work the very first time the service is installed on the box.

Comment: @Kevin Visual Studio's Code Analysis suggests that objects should not be disposed more than one time, `process.Close()` line is useless.

Comment: @Contango can you explain further ?

Comment: @JohnTube--removed the process.Close() line

Comment: Note that the syntax may look strange to some but `reset= 0` is correct, and `reset=0` is incorrect. The correct use of spaces is crucial, `reset=` is one argument, followed by a space, then `0`.

Comment: The 60000 is in ms (i.e 1 minute) and is the "Restart service after" field

Comment: The script "sc failure [servicename] reset= 0 actions= restart/60000" config to restart the service on both 1st, 2nd and subsequent fails. how can it be configured only for the first failure option?

Comment: @Liam I tried `actions= restart/6000` (with space) and it didn't work, I checked it in properties of the service but `actions=restart/6000` did. I am not sure about `reset= ` vs `reset=` as I am not able to find this value in any query or even UI. Please clarify.

Comment: Thank you! I have been searcing for this in a long time.. :)

Comment: WARNING: if you do this from PowerShell, it won't work, because `sc` is a built-in alias for `Set-Content`. From PowerShell, you need to do `sc.exe ....` See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33782385/.

Answer (score 14):

After many attemps, I resolved it using **sc** command line app.

I have batch file with installutil and sc. My batch file is similar to:

```
installutil.exe "path to your service.exe"
sc failure "your service name" reset= 300 command= "some exe file to execute" actions= restart/20000/run/1000/reboot/1000
```

If you want the full documentation of sc command, follow this link: [SC.exe: Communicates with the Service Controller and installed services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sc-config)

*Note: You need to add an space after each equal (=) symbol. Example:  reset= 300*

Answer (score 9):

I don't think it's part of the .NET API, but this might help:

[A ServiceInstaller Extension That Enables Recovery and Autostart Configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/sercviceinstallerext.aspx)

[Install a Windows service the way YOU want to! (C# version)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/csharpwindowsserviceinst.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I found the following project which takes care of these settings, using only code and Win API calls:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSWindowsServiceRecoveryPro-2147e7ac

Comment: Your link is broken! [Link only answers are bad!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259)

Comment: The link works and this is the best solution. Works without a process start.

Comment: If you want to do it in code only, use the ChangeServiceConfig2 function. See: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6164/A-ServiceInstaller-Extension-That-Enables-Recovery