# Fault Recovery in C#

Tags: winforms, sms, c#-3.0, recovery

I have a SMS application in C# Windows Forms which needs to run 24*7 . However everytime there is an exception coming up which causes the application to terminate its execution and start after 60 sec (Its in scheduled tasks).
My requirement is that it should start in 10 sec after catching the exception . Is there is any classes or methods in C# for fault recovery ?

Comment: do you have the code for the app?

Comment: What is the nature of the exception(is an application restart necessary?), and what problems do you run into when you do regular try-catch exception handling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run an application 24*7 you should create a [Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412(v=vs.100).aspx) it can be configured at install time to restart in case of failures. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633429/install-windows-service-with-recovery-action-to-restart) for details.

Furthermore you might want add an [UnhandledExceptionEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.unhandledexceptioneventhandler.aspx) to your default application domain by registering it on the [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx). Another interesting event is [Application.ThreadException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx) which can be used to handle exceptions occurring in Windows Forms threads.

Comment: I tried windows service but it was crashing my application and then we  need to restart the server. It was not handling exception properly