# Along with my hosted Windows service's installer, is it possible to set the recovery options when errors occur?

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, servicehost, hosted

I'm following along with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx to host my service as a Windows service. It installs just fine, but I would like to actually set the recovery options to "Restart the Service" on a "First failure", "Second failure", or "Subsequent failure". How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The options for doing so are not simple, they require invoking some methods to pull it off. You could use something like the following extension, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6164/A-ServiceInstaller-Extension-That-Enables-Recovery or rolling your own using the commands.

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint="ChangeServiceConfig2")]
public static extern bool 
ChangeServiceFailureActions( IntPtr hService, int dwInfoLevel,
[ MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.Struct ) ] ref SERVICE_FAILURE_ACTIONS lpInfo );


[DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint="ChangeServiceConfig2")]
public static extern bool 
ChangeServiceDescription( IntPtr hService, int dwInfoLevel, 
[ MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.Struct ) ] ref SERVICE_DESCRIPTION lpInfo );
```

See http://netcode.ru/dotnet/?lang=&katID=30&skatID=277&artID=7660 for more information

Comment: Ah, this seems like the more proper way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can set recovery options using sc.exe from the command line.  This answer has a good example of how to do this using C#:

[Install Windows Service with Recovery action to Restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633429/install-windows-service-with-recovery-action-to-restart)

Comment: Is there no better, more built-in way?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: For the record, I went with doing it this way. The above method is the better way to invoke it, but intent is not as clear to someone reading your code. I think this is the clearest way to achieve this.