# How to install a windows service with "First Failure" set to "Restart the Service" C#

Tags: c#, windows, service

I am using this method to create a windows service.

```
public void InstallService(string username, string password, string configurationUser, string configurationPassword)
{
    var installationPath = GetInstallationPath();
    var process = installationPath + @"myservice.exe ";
    args = "-install " + username + " " + password;
    InstallProcessWithLogOn(process, args, username, password, configurationUser, configurationPassword, 90 * 1000);
    // InstallProcessWithLogOn uses the method CreateProcessWithLogonW
}
```

As default, my service, in the Recovery tab, has "Take no action" at First failure, Second failure and Third failure.

How can I modify my method such that when the service is created it has the option set as "Restart the Service" for First failure, Second failure and Third failure?

LE : Is there any way of configuring that service using advapi32.dll's method CreateProcessWithLogonW? Or something else from advapi32.dll?

Comment: Have you tried the `ServiceInstaller` provided by .Net?

Comment: We'd need to have *some clue* about what `myservice.exe` *actually does* when run with the `-install` argument to have a chance of being able to answer this.

Comment: How does knowing what myservice.exe help you? I just want to configure the service such that it has those options set in the Recovery Tab when installing it.

Comment: @dizzyOWNZ - because you're not showing us the code that *installs the service*, and it's *that* code that is likely to need updating/changing/replacing.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I think you are right, I'm going to investigate that file and come back to an answer but so far the solution below will work for now.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Is there any way of modifying the serivice using advapi32.dll?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this issue with a Service that I had a while back. I am not sure if you can do this directly in code, but you *can* set it manually at a command prompt by calling `sc failure`. The option that I ended up using was to execute the command after the Installation had been committed, by attaching to the [Install.Commited](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.committed(v=vs.110).aspx) event handler

```
var serviceName = "YourWindowsServiceName";
var resetAfter = 60000;
Process.Start("cmd.exe", $"/c sc failure \"{serviceName}\" reset= 0 actions= restart/{resetAfter}/restart/{resetAfter}/restart/{resetAfter}");
```

The actions parameter above takes a slash delimited set of configurations. They alternate between Action and Time (in ms). So the Above looks like:

- FirstFailure: restart @ 60seconds
- Second Failure: restart @ 60seconds
- Third Failure: restart @ 60seconds

See more about [sc failure](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742019(v=ws.11).aspx).

Comment: This technique is used in the accepted answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/6877830/491907

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.  Have can I check whether the Committed event handler is being called from the ServiceInstaller ?